# How to get all details of exception including errorMsg, url & lineNumber using $exceptionHandler?

Tags: angularjs

I want to setup JS exception logging module in my angularJS application and for this I am using **$exceptionHandler**.

I am using following code to log app errors :

```
app.config(function($provide) {
    $provide.decorator("$exceptionHandler", function($delegate) {
        return function(exception, cause) {
            $delegate(exception, cause);
            // alert(exception.message);
            console.log(JSON.stringify(exception.message += ' (caused by "' + cause + '")'));
        };
    });
});
```

But here,I am getting only message but I want all details related to exception like errorMsg, url, line number etc.

How to get all this details using above code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it turns out the only part of the [error object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error) that's standardized is the message. Both lineNumber, and fileName will give inconsistent results across different browser versions.

The most general way of getting as much detail about the exception that you can might be this:

```
app.config(function($provide) {
    $provide.decorator("$exceptionHandler", function($delegate) {
        return function(exception, cause) {
            $delegate(exception, cause);

            var formatted = '';
            var properties = '';
            formatted += 'Exception: "' + exception.toString() + '"\n';
            formatted += 'Caused by: ' + cause + '\n';

            properties += (exception.message) ? 'Message: ' + exception.message + '\n' : ''
            properties += (exception.fileName) ? 'File Name: ' + exception.fileName + '\n' : ''
            properties += (exception.lineNumber) ? 'Line Number: ' + exception.lineNumber + '\n' : ''
            properties += (exception.stack) ? 'Stack Trace: ' + exception.stack + '\n' : ''

            if (properties) {
              formatted += properties;
            }

            console.log(formatted);
        };
    });
});
```

Comment: I am not getting any stack trace here. Properties is also blank.

Comment: Still it is not coming, I am getting ==> Exception: "ReferenceError: sharedServic is not defined"
Caused by: <div ng-view="" id="loadingDiv" class="ng-scope">
Properties:

Comment: Sorry about that. Turns out you can't iterate over the Error object keys in (at least) Chrome. In my haste to make the snippet work I made a few more mistakes...

Comment: @klyd right, that works in Firefox but not in Chrome (can't say anything regarding other browsers). I worked thet around with parsing stack trace: ```exception.stack.match(/(http:\/\/.*\.js):(\d+):(\d+)/)``` will return array containing file name, line and column number. Not sure how universal this soultion is.