# AngularJS code not executing InternetExplorer when Developer Tools are closed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer, ie-developer-tools

Unfortunately I've stumbled upon a problem with my application. When running in Internet Explorer.

I earlier found that it could be related to a console.log problem, but there is no console.log anywhere in my code. However, when opening the console (F12 Developer Tools) the application runs as expected.

Could it be related to $parent.$on function?

```
 $scope.$parent.$on("updateCart", function (e) {
        shoppingCartService.getItems().then(function (d) {

                vm.items = d;

        });
    });
```

Comment: I am familiar with a "no cache" option in Chrome dev tools. Maybe something along those line - some option that is enabled only while the tools are open?

Comment: any more info please, is it working in Chrome and Firefox without dev tools / console open? What error does it give you? What doesn't work exactly?

Comment: Yeah sorry, been so caught up in trying to fix the error. The code does indeed work in Firefox, Chrome and Safari when the respective console logs are either closed or open. There are no error messages either

Comment: Try adding `<script> if(!window.console){window.console={log:function(){}};}</script>` to top of your page, to make sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It cannot be related to that, and I'm fairly sure it is in fact console.log but in a place where you don't expect it.

You can debug JavaScript without the developer console by alerting all errors:

```
window.onerror = function(msg, url, linenumber) {
    alert('Error message: '+msg+'\nURL: '+url+'\nLine Number: '+linenumber);
    return true;
}
```

Or by including Firebug lite: https://getfirebug.com/firebuglite

---

Update: if errors still don't show up, try overriding AngularJS's exception handler: (see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/25285528/451480)

```
YOURAPP.factory('$exceptionHandler', function() {
  return function(exception, cause) {
    alert('Error message: '+exception.message+'\nURL: '+exception.fileName+'\nLine Number: '+exception.lineNumber+'\nCause: '+cause);
  };
});
```

Comment: thanks. I inserted firebug lite and the window.onerror function. but unfortunately IE is not displaying any notifications in the console or alerting an error message ;(

Comment: I updated my post with a way to override NG's $exceptionHandler, can you try that?

Comment: no luck sir, your code does work, i forced an error and it displayed for that.

Comment: So the problem is: the code in your post works correctly in Internet Explorer when the developer console is open, but when you close your console, the code is not working? -- I think we need more information to solve the issue. Can you post the code for the entire controller that listens to `updateCart`, the controller that broadcasts `updateCart` and the code for `shoppingCartService`? Because the problem is probably not in the code that you posted.

Comment: You're onto it. I found it to be relevenat to IE and caching. The shoppingCartService for getItems was cached. I appended the URL of the string to "?" + new Date().getTime(); now each request is unique for the client. Thanks for your help sir.